# Не выполняется MYSQL запрос в скрипте

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Проблема в следующем: генерится строка из выбранных параметров

```
$query = SELECT * FROM catalog_test WHERE TRUE ".$where;
```

потом `$query` передается в `mysqli->query($query);`
и дальше ничего не происходит,никаких сообщений об ошибке.
Вывожу `$query` на экран для визуальной проверки,получается например:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM catalog_test 
 WHERE TRUE AND picture = '+' AND ( name LIKE('%Ariocarpus %') 
    OR name LIKE('%Astrophytum %') OR name LIKE('%Aylostera %') OR FALSE)
```

И самое интересное что этот запрос работает!

В чем проблема?
Если этому запросу присвоить $query,то он успешно выполняется,но с параметрами никак не хочет.
Спасибо

Comment: отформатируйте сообщение, проверьте что пишет

`echo $mysqli->error;`

и объясните назначение `WHERE TRUE AND`

Comment: Чем именно непонятен вопрос?
После выполнения запроса ничего не происходит,хотя если скопировать получившуюся строку запроса и выполнить напрямую,то он работает.
Поэтому спрашиваю еще раз, чем именно непонятен мой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Запрос надо в кавычки одинарные взять

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM catalog_test WHERE TRUE AND picture = $where';
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. Опять ничего не происходит, но напрямую запрос выполняется.(т.е. строка формируется верно)

Comment: учитывая, что переменная where уже содержит одинарную кавычку, ответ не совсем верный. Кавычки внутри нужно эскейпить. Либо использовать двойные кавычки.

Comment: @cerberus учите строки, подстановка переменных в одинарных кавычках не осуществляется

Comment: KoVadim,можно поподробней про кавычки?
Выяснил, если присвоить только $where = ' AND picture = "+"'
Запрос работает.
А когда в $where содержится еще 
AND ( name LIKE('%Ariocarpus %') OR name LIKE('%Astrophytum %') OR name LIKE('%Aylostera %') OR FALSE)
то не работает

Comment: Проблема решена!!

Если кому интересно, ошибка была не в запросе (как я и думал), а в поле таблицы, по которому шел поиск, в названии каждой строки скрылся символ перевода строки,поэтому запрос был пустой.